# Selecting Option on a Javascript dropdown

Tags: javascript, vba

I'm trying to select an option from a dropdown list on a webpage through VBA.
I was able to do it with GetelementbyId like below, because the Options are listed in the HTML code.

```
 IE.Document.getElementById("Dominio").Value = "yadayada"
```

First HTML Section:

```
<select name="Dominio" id="Dominio" class="campoSelect1" 
style="width:262px;">
<option value="yadayada">Yadayada</option>
```

Although, for another dropdown list I'm not able to do it, I guess because the Options are in a javascript function and not listed in the HTML code. Any thoughts on this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Second HTML Section:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
    <div id="contenido" class="contenidoPanel">
        <div>
            <h2>Planificación Semanal</h2>
            <div class="hr"></div>
            <div id="contenedorOpciones" style="width: 700px" class="formulario">

                <div class="formulario-inline">
                    <label id="Label2">Unidad Negocio:</label>
                    <select id="UnidadesNegocio" style="width: 150px" onchange="javascript:rellenaSubproyectosConsolidados();">
                    </select>
                    <label id="Label3">Subproyecto:</label>
                    <select id="subproyecto" style="width: 340px" onchange="javascript:rellenaservicio();">
                    </select>
                </div>
...
```

Comment: Are you sure the select from second section actually has options in it?

Comment: Yes there are options. I've tried also something like this but it didn't work. 
    'IE.document.getElementByID("UnidadesNegocio").Focus
    IE.document.getElementByID("UnidadesNegocio").SelectedIndex = 0
    IE.document.getElementByID("UnidadesNegocio").FireEvent ("onchange")'

Comment: It seems like smth is forcing select population later. Can you try to get the data from it after some timeout e,g `setTimeout(getDataFromSelect, 2000)`